# The python parser does not read information from the site, but returns None

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm making a python parser for the site: https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/

The task is to pick film genres from films (displayed on the page as: 'span', class _ = 'selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item')

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.1 (Windows NT 7.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0',
           'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}

def get_html(url, params = ''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('span', class_='selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item')
    cards = []

    for item in items:
        cards.append(
            {
                'title': item.find('span', class_='title')
            }
        )
    return cards


html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

I can't understand why it gives the result: [{'title': None}, {'title': None}, {'title': None}, ... {'title': None}]

Comment: You're getting a CAPTCHA, so your `soup` is empty.

Comment: No, i use VPN to didn't get CAPTCHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm definitely getting some `captcha` blocks from my local machine

> https://www.kinopoisk.ru/**showcaptcha**?cc=1&retpath=https%3A//www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250%3F_ea4584...

but running from google colab I was able to reproduce your error, and since you are running from a VPN you probably will not encounter this issue.

The real issue here is that `items` doesn't have any class `title`, so naturally your dictionary is being filled with `None`. Since the class you are looking for has a similar sibling (`span` with the same class name for `country`), you would have to skip every other element from the result to get only the film genres.

```html
<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">США</span>
<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">мультфильм, фэнтези</span>
<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">США</span>
<span class="selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item">мультфильм, комедия</span>
```

I would suggest the use a parent element to be able to extract multiple informations from each film card with more specificity.

```py
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='selection-film-item-meta selection-film-item-meta_theme_desktop')

    cards = []
    for item in items:
        title = item.find('p', {'class':'selection-film-item-meta__name'})
        additional = item.find_all('span', {'class':'selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item'})
        cards.append(
            {
                'title': title.get_text(),
                'country': additional[0].get_text(),
                'genre': additional[1].get_text(),
            }
        )
    return cards
```

```py
[{
    'title': 'Аватар: Легенда об Аанге',
    'country': 'США',
    'genre': 'мультфильм, фэнтези'
}, {
    'title': 'Гравити Фолз',
    'country': 'США',
    'genre': 'мультфильм, комедия'
}, {
    'title': 'Друзья',
    'country': 'США',
    'genre': 'комедия, мелодрама'
}, {
...
...
```